# Using Delphi, what tool can i use to decode MP3 to WAV?

Tags: delphi

Is there a tool or some code sample in **delphi** i can use to read and decode mp3 file format to PCM WAV format?

Searched on the internet but didn't get anything that is helping.

Gath

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [Audio Components Suite](http://www.mtu-net.ru/aborovsky/acs/).

Comment: Great! Worked like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use DSPack component to access Windows Media Format API.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont mind rolling up your sleeves a little, you can use DirectShow directly.